# PhpStorm not typehinting class method return types in trait

Tags: php, phpstorm, php-7, type-hinting, phpstorm-2017.2

Suppose i have a set of classes

```php
class A {

    use Dummy;

    function getB() : B { ... }

}

class B {

    function foo() { ... }

}



trait Dummy {

    function works() {
        if ($this instanceof A)
            $this -> getB() -> foo();   // Typehinting works
    }

    function doesntWork() {
        $this -> getB() -> foo(); // Method foo not found in...
    }

}
```

How do I get PhpStorm to get typehinting work as supposed in method `doesntWork`? I really get annoyed by this because lots of my work relies on using main class methods in traits like this and I get lots of distracting yellow color in PhpStorm...

Comment: Settings > Language & Framework > PHP > PHP Language Level > PHP 7

Comment: @Fky, it's set to php7.1

Comment: @Fky this does not make any sense. Anyway if it doesn't work any setting won't change that. You should report an issue in phpStorm's issue tracker. This looks like a bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do much right now -- it's an IDE issue.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-35952 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Related: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-39004

Comment: Oh, I was actually searching for it on youtrack and missed, thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1):

It turns out there's a workaround. In that case,

```
/**
* @method \Namespace\Name\B getB
*/
trait Dummy { ... }
```

A bit ugly but works

Comment: Yes, it's a pretty "dirty" workaround (makes little sense to add such tags -- unless you just wish to satisfy particular IDE). Did not wanted to mention it here (although I have tried the same in my own code but with properties). But it can be used for time being...